# Use Android objects outside Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In a Java project I am using a class that is in an Android project and uses an android View object. When I try and use that class in the non-android project I get a no class found error at runtime. How can I import android.widget.view.View into a non-android project? Can I add it to my project build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the android platform runtime, ie.. DalvikVM, etc... you will not be able to run any of the framework necessary to render "Views" in your Java project. Did you think of that?. But to get it coded you would at least need to import Android.jar into your Java project build path. It will likely find the Widget package, but the Widget package will be looking for the Android SDK, etc...

What does android.widget.View give you outside of the Android environment??

Comment: I have a helper program that makes java object files for the android app to download off my web server to get updates to content in the app.

Comment: Use a more generic interchange format for these objects, rather than trying to make them “Java objects”. That way, you can refactor your code in the future without breaking the interchange format, or going through hoops (adding a legacy compatibility layer) to keep it the same.

Comment: I agree with using a more generic format for the files being downloaded. Without knowing more about what you really want to accomplish there's not much more to add.